# filter by excluding specific values from multiple columns (AND) from repository function jpa ,java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with records. 
This table has year (int) and month (int).
I want to filter out the combination of them and get the rest.

Is

`public List<T> findAllByYearAndMonthNot(int year,int month)`

going to work or it need

`public List<T> findAllByYearNotAndMonthNot(int year,int month)`

or is it something else?

If I place date in the DB table . Is it possible if I use

```
public List<T> filterAllByDateBetweenNot(Date date1, Date Date2)
```

Comment: It is possible, see here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: i get error when i user BetweenNot cause it things that Between is property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the @Query annotation like this:

```
@Query("select i from Item i where not (i.year = ?1 and i.month = ?2)")
List<Item> findAllByNotYearAndMonth(int year, int month)
```

Where Item is your database entity having year and month fields.

Comment: This excludes the year and keeps only this month. I want to exclude both year and month combination

Comment: You are right, I forgot the parentheses. I just edited the answer